# Xamarin live player errors when building

Tags: xamarin

I have my Samsung Galaxy S8 paired to Xamarin Live player, but when I start running my app, I am getting 27 errors all the time. I won't get these errors when building without Live Player.

This is the whole output (I removed something in the middle because it was too long):

```
Start TimeToSport.Android, Samsung SM-G950F Player, .
Attempting connection to debug address: 192.168.2.41:37847.
Connected to: 192.168.2.41:37847.
Deploying E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\TimeToSport.Android.csproj...
Got device info: Samsung SM-G950F Player (Android) @ 192.168.2.41:37847
Synchronizing files...
Building and running...
Built with 55 messages.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineSize2' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineHeight3' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineHeight3U' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\GegevensInvullen\GegevensPersoonlijk.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The field 'GegevensPersoonlijk.gegevensSportDoel' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The field 'ItemsPage.etenVoorTijdText2' is assigned but its value is never used
(1,1): error: Position 37:160. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'FontSize', or mismatching type between value and property.
(1,1): error: Position 31:14. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'TitleView', or mismatching type between value and property.
(1,1): error: Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll"
File name: '/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/FormsViewGroup.dll'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 <---
<---

(1,1): error: Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll"
File name: '/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 <---
<---

(1,1): error: Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll"
File name: '/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 <---
<---


(1,1): error: Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll"
File name: '/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/.nuget/packages/xforms.plugin.animationnavigationpage/1.0.5/lib/MonoAndroid10/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001b7] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00011] in <5b4cad9611b47c3aa745038396ad4c5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 <---
<---

E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineSize2' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineHeight3' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The variable 'lineHeight3U' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\GegevensInvullen\GegevensPersoonlijk.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The field 'GegevensPersoonlijk.gegevensSportDoel' is assigned but its value is never used
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport\Views\Main\ItemsPage.xaml.cs(1,1): warning: The field 'ItemsPage.etenVoorTijdText2' is assigned but its value is never used
(1,1): error: Position 37:160. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'FontSize', or mismatching type between value and property.
(1,1): error: Position 31:14. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'TitleView', or mismatching type between value and property.
(1,1): error: Dependent project TimeToSport.csproj failed to build, using old version.
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\Renderers\DatePickerCtrlRenderer.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'DatePickerCtrl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\Renderers\DatePickerCtrlRenderer.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'CustomControls' does not exist in the namespace 'DatePickerDefaultTextDemo' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\MainActivity.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\Renderers\DatePickerCtrlRenderer.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'DatePickerCtrl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\Renderers\DatePickerCtrlRenderer.cs(1,1): error: The type or namespace name 'DatePickerCtrl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\Renderers\DatePickerCtrlRenderer.cs(1,1): warning: 'DatePickerRenderer.DatePickerRenderer()' is obsolete: 'This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use DatePickerRenderer(Context) instead.'
E:\Xamarin Projects\TimeToSport_master\TimeToSport\TimeToSport.Android\MainActivity.cs(1,1): warning: The field 'MainActivity._navigationView' is never used
Failed to debug your app.
```

Anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: `(1,1): error: Position 31:14. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'TitleView', or mismatching type between value and property.` You can provide some code about  `TitleView`.

Comment: I deleted the TitleView cause I didn't need it anyway, but now I'm getting the following errors: https://i.gyazo.com/de49316aa66d389cd10919d753e98c54.png. The first error I can't manage to fix already from the line `LoadApplication(new App());`?

Comment: Check portable Class Library should be loaded in Xamarin Studio. It needs to be loaded and included in the build configuration so it's compiled as well.

Comment: @johnheaven You mean this? https://i.gyazo.com/eb704af36dcf5e3c0a86564c26583bd7.png, this was already checked